# Odd Column returns when scraping with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am learning python and trying to build a scraper to glean parts data from a suppliers site. My issue now is that I am getting different column counts from my parsed table rows where I know that each row has the same column count. The issue has to be something I am overlooking and after two days of trying different things I am asking for a few more sets of eyes on my code to locate my error. Not having much python coding experience is no doubt my biggest hurdle.

First, the data. Rather than paste the html I have stored in my database, I'll give you a link to the live site I have crawled and stored in my db. The first link is [this one](http://wixfilters.com/filterlookup/index2.asp?Section=1&Make=1&SubMake=&Model=74492&SubModel=-1&Engine=&Year=1997&TempSection=1&TempMake=1&TempModel=74492&TempEngine=&TempSubModel=-1&TempYear=1997).

The issue is that I get mostly correct results. However, every so often I get the values skewed in the column count. I can't seem to locate the cause.

Here is an example of the flawed result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record: 1 Section:Passenger  /  Light Truck Make: ACURA SubMake: 
Model: CL SubModel:  Year: 1997 Engine: L4 1.6L 1590cc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 1 part Air Filter
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 2 2 
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 3 part_no 46395
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 4 filter_loc 
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 5 engine 
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 6 vin_code V6 3.0L 2997cc
Rec:1 Row 6 Col 7 comment Engine Code J30A1
```

** Note that the engine value has been shifted to the vin_code field.

And proof it works some of the time:

---

```
Record: 2 Section:Passenger  /  Light Truck Make: ACURA SubMake: 
Model: CL SubModel:  Year: 1998 Engine: L4 1.6L 1590cc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 1 part Oil Filter
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 2 2 
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 3 part_no 51334
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 4 filter_loc 
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 5 engine L4 2.3L 2254cc
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 6 vin_code
Rec:3 Row 4 Col 7 comment Engine Code F23A1
```

** Note the fields line up in this record...

I suspect either there is something in the table cells my parser is not looking for or I have missed something trivial.

Here is the important portion of my code:

```
# Per Query
while records:
    # Per Query Loop
    #print str(records)
    for record in records:
        print 'Record Count:'+str(rec_cnt)
        items = ()
        item = {}
        source = record['doc']
        page = html.fromstring(source)

        for rows in page.xpath('//div/table'):
            #records = []
            item = {}
            cntx = 0
            for row in list(rows):
                cnty = 0 # Column Counter
                found_oil = 0 # Found oil filter record flag
                data = {} # Data
                # Data fields
                field_data = {'part':'',   'part_no':'', 'filter_loc':'',  'engine':'',  'vin_code':'',  'comment':'', 'year':''}
                print
                print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
                print 'Record: '+str(record['id']), 'Section:'+str(record['section']),  'Make: '+str(record['make']),   'SubMake: '+str(record['submake'])
                print  'Model: '+str(record['model']),  'SubModel: '+str(record['submodel']),  'Year: '+str(record['year']),  'Engine: '+str(record['engine'])
                print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

                #
                # Rules for extracting data columns
                # 1. First column always has a link to the bullet image
                # 2. Second column is part name
                # 3. Third column always empty
                # 4. Fourth column is  part number
                # 5. Fith column is empty
                # 6. Sixth column is part location
                # 7. Seventh column is always empty
                # 8. Eigth column is engine size
                # 9. Ninth column is vin code
                # 10. Tenth column is COmment
                # 11. Eleventh column does not exist.
                #
                for column in row.xpath('./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()="0xa0"] | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()="\n"]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmeduim"]/img[@src]/text()  | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()=""]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"]/b/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"]/a/text() |./td[@class="blackmedium"]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()=" "]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()="&#160"]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()=None]/text()'): 
                    #' | ./td[position()>1]/a/text() | ./td[position()>1]/text() | self::node()[position()=1]/td/text()'):
                    cnty+=1
                    if ('Oil Filter' == column.strip() or 'Air Filter' == column.strip()) and found_oil == 0:
                        found_oil = 1

                    if found_oil == 1:
                        print 'Rec:'+str(rec_cnt), 'Row '+str(cntx),  'Col '+str(cnty),  _fields[cnty],  column.strip()
                        #cnty+= 1
                        #print
                    else:
                        print 'Rec: '+str(rec_cnt),  'Col: '+str(cnty)

                    field_data[ str(_fields[cnty]) ] = str(column.strip())
                    #cnty = cnty+1

                # Save data to db dest table
                if found_oil == 1:
                    data['source_id'] = record['id']
                    data['section_id'] = record['section_id']
                    data['section'] = record['section']
                    data['make_id'] = record['make_id']
                    data['make'] = record['make']
                    data['submake_id'] = record['submake_id']
                    data['submake'] = record['submake']
                    data['model_id'] = record['model_id']
                    data['model'] = record['model']
                    data['submodel_id'] = record['submodel_id']
                    data['submodel'] = record['submodel']
                    data['year_id'] = record['year_id']
                    data['year'] = record['year']
                    data['engine_id'] = record['engine_id']
                    data['engine'] = record['engine']
                    data['part'] = field_data['part']
                    data['part_no'] = field_data['part_no']
                    data['filter_loc'] = field_data['filter_loc']
                    data['vin_code'] = field_data['vin_code']
                    data['comment'] = conn.escape_string(field_data['comment'])

                    data['url'] = record['url']
                    save_data(data)
                    print 'Filed Data:'
                    print field_data

                cntx+=1
            rec_cnt+=1
    #End main per query loop 
    delay() # delay if wait was passed on cmd line
    records = get_data()
    has_offset = 1
    #End Queries
```

Thank you all for your help and your eyes...

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I run into a problem like this, I do two things:

1. Break the problem down into smaller chunks. Use python functions or classes to perform subsets of functionality so that you can test the functions individually for correctness.
2. Use the [Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to inspect the code as it runs to understand where it's failing. For example, in this case, I would add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the line that says `cnty+=1`.

Then, when the code runs, you'll get an interactive interpreter at that point and you can inspect the various variables and discover why you're not getting what you expect.

A couple of tips for using pdb:

Use `c` to allow the program to continue (until the next breakpoint or set_trace); Use `n` to step to the next line in the program. Use `q` to raise an Exception (and usually abort).

Comment: I can tell you that by single steping through the code that some columns are not being returned by the line:                    for column in row.xpath('./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()="0xa0"] | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()="\n"]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmeduim"]/img[@src]/text()  | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()=""]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"]/b/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"]/a/text() |./td[@class="blackmedium"]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()=" "]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()="&#160"]/text() | ./td[@class="blackmedium"][text()=None]/text()')

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the details of your scrapping process?  The intermittent failures could be based on the parsing of the html data.

Comment: I crawled the site using another app I wrote (my first python app) and stored the page in a mysql database. I then pull the pages from my MySQL database and I have check to make sure I amd getting the correct results from the database. The issue is in the column loop. It seems that the lxml query for the columns is not returning all the columns. The issue seems to be with certain empty cloumns from what I can tell. But looking at the html I can't find a rhym or reason for the issue.

Comment: This site wont let me post any more code. I was going to post the whole app. But as I said, the issue seems to be that lxml is not finding all the columns. Not sure why...

Comment: Thanks I will reset and review.

Comment: Messing around a little more I think the issue may be that some table cells have no content. Not even a space. i.e. <td class="blackmedium"><td>  How does one use lxml to locate this type of cell and how do you test if for the non-existance of a text property?

Comment: Sorry I am using xml.etree.ElementTree and xml.dom.minidom to do my parsing so no advice on lxml.  Sounds like you have your intermittent factor narrowed down and you're are close to the fix.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your xpath expression searches for text nodes. No matches are found for empty cells, causing your code to "skip" columns. Try iterating over the `td` elements themselves, and then "look down" from the element to its contents. To get you started:

```
# just iterate over child elements of the row, which are always td
# use enumerate to easily get a counter for the columns
for col_no, td in enumerate(row, start=1):
    # use the xpath function string() to get the string value for the element
    # this will yield an empty string for empty elements
    print col_no, td.xpath('string()')
```

Note that the use of the `string()` xpath function may in some cases be not enough/too simple for what you want. In your example, you may find something like `<td><a>51334</a><sup>53</sup></td>` (see oil filter). My example would give you "5133453", where you would seem to need "51334" (not sure if that was intentional or if you hadn't noticed the "missing" part, if you do want only the in the hyperlink, use `td.findtext('a')`)

Comment: THanks. The <sup>53</sup> is the super text to identify a note that I do not need. I am only after the part number.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone who has given aid to me these past few days. All your input has resulted in a working application that I am now using. I wanted to post the resulting changes to my code so those who look here may find an answer or at least information on how they may also tackle their issue. Below is the rewritten portion of my code that solved the issues I was having:

```
#
# get_column_index()
# returns a dict of column names/column number pairs
#
def get_column_index(row): 
    index = {}
    col_no = 0
    td = None
    name = ''
    for col_no,  td in enumerate(row,  start=0):
        mystr = str(td.xpath('string()').encode('ascii',  'replace'))
        name =  str.lower(mystr).replace(' ', '_')
        idx = name.replace('.', '')
        index[idx] =  col_no

    if int(options.verbose) > 2:
        print 'Field Index:',  str(index)

    return index




def run():
    global has_offset
    records = get_data()

    #print 'Records',  records
    rec_cnt = 0

    # Per Query
    while records:
        # Per Query Loop
        #print str(records)
        for record in records:
            if int(options.verbose) > 0:
                print 'Record Count:'+str(rec_cnt)

            items = ()
            item = {}
            source = record['doc']
            page = html.fromstring(source)
            col_index = {}

            for rows in page.xpath('//div/table'):
                #records = []
                item = {}
                cntx = 0
                for row in list(rows):
                    data = {} # Data
                    found_oil = 0 #found proper part flag
                    # Data fields
                    field_data = {'part':'',   'part_no':'', 'part_note':'',  'filter_loc':'',  'engine':'',  'vin_code':'',  'comment':'', 'year':''}

                    if int(options.verbose) > 0:
                        print
                        print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
                        print 'Row'+str(cntx), 'Record: '+str(record['id']), 'Section:'+str(record['section']),  'Make: '+str(record['make']),   'SubMake: '+str(record['submake'])
                        print  'Model: '+str(record['model']),  'SubModel: '+str(record['submodel']),  'Year: '+str(record['year']),  'Engine: '+str(record['engine'])
                        print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

                   # get column indexes
                    if cntx == 1:
                        col_index = get_column_index(row)

                    if col_index != None and cntx > 1:
                        found_oil = 0

                        for col_no,  td in enumerate(row):

                            if ('part' in col_index) and (col_no == col_index['part']):
                                part = td.xpath('string()').strip()
                                if 'Oil Filter' == part or 'Air Filter' == part or 'Fuel Filter' == part or 'Transmission Filter' == part:
                                    found_oil = 1
                                    field_data['part'] = td.xpath('string()').strip()

                            # Part Number
                            if ('part_no' in col_index) and (col_no == col_index['part_no']):
                                field_data['part_no'] = str(td.xpath('./a/text()')).strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '')
                                field_data['part_note'] = str(td.xpath('./sup/text()')).strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '')

                            # Filter Location
                            if ('filterloc' in col_index) and (col_no == col_index['filterloc']):
                                field_data['filter_loc'] = td.xpath('string()').strip()

                            # Engine
                            if ('engine' in col_index) and (col_no == col_index['engine']):
                                field_data['engine'] = td.xpath('string()').strip()

                            if ('vin_code' in col_index) and (col_no == col_index['vin_code']):
                                field_data['vin_code'] = td.xpath('string()').strip()

                            if ('comment' in col_index) and (col_no == col_index['comment']):
                                field_data['comment'] = td.xpath('string()').strip()

                            if int(options.verbose) == 0:
                                print ',' 


                        if int(options.verbose) > 0:
                            print 'Field Data: ',  str(field_data)
                        elif int(options.verbose) == 0:
                            print '.'

                    # Save data to db dest table
                    if found_oil == 1:
                        data['source_id'] = record['id']
                        data['section_id'] = record['section_id']
                        data['section'] = record['section']
                        data['make_id'] = record['make_id']
                        data['make'] = record['make']
                        data['submake_id'] = record['submake_id']
                        data['submake'] = record['submake']
                        data['model_id'] = record['model_id']
                        data['model'] = record['model']
                        data['submodel_id'] = record['submodel_id']
                        data['submodel'] = record['submodel']
                        data['year_id'] = record['year_id']
                        data['year'] = record['year']
                        data['engine_id'] = record['engine_id']
                        data['engine'] = field_data['engine'] #record['engine']
                        data['part'] = field_data['part']
                        data['part_no'] = field_data['part_no']
                        data['part_note'] = field_data['part_note']
                        data['filter_loc'] = field_data['filter_loc']
                        data['vin_code'] = field_data['vin_code']
                        data['comment'] = conn.escape_string(field_data['comment'])

                        data['url'] = record['url']
                        save_data(data)
                        found_oil = 0

                        if int(options.verbose) > 2:
                            print 'Data:', str(data)

                    cntx+=1
                rec_cnt+=1
        #End main per query loop 
        delay() # delay if wait was passed on cmd line
        records = get_data()
        has_offset = 1
        #End Queries
```